# Can we turn any undirected graph into a directed one such that the difference between in- and out-degree of each vertex is at most 1?

Tags: algorithm, graph, nodes, directed-graph, undirected-graph

Given any undirected graph G, is there always a way to add directions to its edges such that the difference between in-degree and out-degree of each vertex is not greater than 1?

Consider for instance G is defined by vertices 1, 2, and 3, and undirected edges 1--2, 1--3, and 2--3. Then, the directed version 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, and 3 -> 1 makes the difference between in- and out-degree is 0 for all vertices.

Answer (score 0):

This question is about [orientations of undirected graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(graph_theory)).

An orientation is Eulerian if the difference between in- and out-degree of each vertex is 0. It turns out that [any graph **with all degrees even** has an Eulerian orientation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361433/orientation-of-edges-on-graphs-with-vertex-degree-constraints). One just has to compute an Eulerian circuit, which always exists in this case, and choose directions according to this circuit.

Using this, [the same question was solved here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396009/prove-the-edges-of-a-multigraph-may-be-oriented-such-that-the-net-degree-of-any) with a clever trick: just add a new vertex and link it to all vertices of odd degree, then compute an Eulerian orientation, and remove the additional vertex!